# Registry defined autoruns ignored

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, autorun

The autoruns defined in the registry key `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` aren't executed at login as they should. Account has admin privileges.
System wide Autoruns at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` do work.

Paths are correct, privileges of the registry key seem in order, no interferring security tools installed, no group policies changed. Windows 10 build 1909

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.
The `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StartupApproved\Run` seems to superimpose all settings.